# Universal Image Loader not working

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to use Universal Image Loader but I have a strange problem.
My application can not load the image. It logged a error which is "Unable to resolve host "baodientu.chinhphu.vn": No address associated with hostname"
Even I try to add another sample code (I checkouted from https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), it's still not displayed.
But I try this url in browser. it is displayed.
My url is http://baodientu.chinhphu.vn/uploaded_vgp/dangdinhnam/20130626/nguoi%20lao%20dong.jpg
Please help me to find the reasons.

Comment: have you tried another url?

Comment: yeah i've tried it, but still no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not problem with ImageLoader.. It has a Problem with Your server side.

There is server down or host name may be wrong or you can not give a permission of Internet to access it..

So try to add permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your permission is correct.check the networkin your device if its working may be it's depends upon the connection api what u used (URLConnection || HttpURLConnection). try to use the following code

```
InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();   

        if (conn instanceof HttpURLConnection){
            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream  = httpConn.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IOException("Unable to create InputStream for image Url:");
            }
        }else{
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();
            stream = conn.getInputStream();
        }
        if (stream == null) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for image Url:" + url);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You can this code to load an image

```
URL url = new URL("http://image10.bizrate-images.com/resize?sq=60&uid=2216744464");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Also you can refer to this link

www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Comment: i'm posting my permissions that i had set below:'  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />'

Answer (score 0):

Add into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Add into your code.

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imgLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));
imgLoader.displayImage(YourImageURL.toString(), YourImageView);
```